# nth-child counter excluding specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to select container's child starting from the first `.box` without the class `.box--full`.

In my case this `box--full` could not exist, so, the `nth-child` selectors are not the same and i'm stuck here...

```
<!-- Example with one full box -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box--full">full</div>
    <div class="box">box 1</div>
    <div class="box">box 2</div>
    <div class="box">box 3</div>
    <div class="box">box 4</div>
    ...
</div>

<!-- Example without full box -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">box 1</div>
    <div class="box">box 2</div>
    <div class="box">box 3</div>
    <div class="box">box 4</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Here is my CSS working in the case there is no box--full.

```
.container {
    .box {
        &:nth-child(3n+1) {
            padding-right: 2%;
        }
        &:nth-child(3n+2) {
            padding: 0 2%;
        }
        &:nth-child(3n+3) {
            padding-left: 2%; 
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use the :not selector but the counter count the .box--full anyway.

Comment: Actually, I think I found a solution! With the `~` selector. I will post the answer if everything is ok ;)

Comment: You can not “exclude” elements with a certain class in nth-child - a child is a child, no matter what class it has or any. But you should be able to format the nth-child differently based on whether it has a sibling with the class `box--full` before it or not, using the general sibling combinator, `~`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the solution, I had to use the `~` selector.
I think my question wasn't clear dippas. I had to select specific child to set specific padding.

In your snippet you are applying properties to every child no matter if that the first, second or third child. So you wasn't able to see my problem but thank you anyway :) !

```
.box {
    &:nth-child(3n+1) {
        padding-right: 4%;
    }
    &:nth-child(3n+2) {
        padding: 0 2%;
    }
    &:nth-child(3n+3) {
        padding-left: 2%; 
    }
    &.box--full {
        padding-right: 0;
    }
    &.box--full ~ .box:nth-child(3n+2) {
        padding-right: 2%;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    &.box--full ~ .box:nth-child(3n+3) {
        padding: 0 2%;
    }
    &.box--full ~ .box:nth-child(3n+4) {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 2%;
    }
}
```